# php & csv: some operations with columns

Tags: php, csv, insert, if-statement, sql-update

My csv looks like this:

```
column1_row1;column2_row1;column3_row1;column4_row1;... column15_row1
column1_row2;column2_row2;column3_row2;column4_row2;... column15_row2
column1_row3;column2_row3;column3_row3;column4_row3;... column15_row3
```

Now for every row I have to find:

1. Where column 12 contains "word" only
2. IF column 10 value is >=5% of column 8 value

On the first line:

1. Look in a database table "alpha" for the corresponding reference number contained in column 4,
2. Insert some data (rows) with certain attributes (like the correct id_number and relative % in format 0,230000 for 23%) into table "beta" (based on another column id)

Insert, update and eventually remove:
Not only do the same procedure but also check and register percentage variations and delete the corresponding row with id_number if the variation (>=5%) is not verified anymore.

**edit:**

I found something like this:

```
$file_handle = fopen("filename.csv", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);

print $line_of_text[0];

}

fclose($file_handle);
```

But if it meets a comma it truncates and I have to avoid, then have to access the column values, I don't need the whole line, and what size instead of 1024 do you suggest if the csv contains many long text descriptions?

Comment: the problem is that i'm not used to manage csv from php and search for some help and guidelines to be able to do what i need. thanks

Comment: It sounds like you know exactly what you need to do, you just need to... do it. Take each step you described, write and test the code for that step, then add in the next part until you're done. http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: i really would to see if the guy who voted down my question is so able to do it fast... instead of having fun to vote down at random :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example csv is semicolon delimited (instead of comma) so you'll need to change your fgetcsv to:

```
$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024, ';');
```

From the PHP Manual for [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php):

> **Length**
>
> It became optional in PHP 5. Omitting this parameter (or setting it to 0 in PHP 5.0.4 and >later) the maximum line length is not limited, which is slightly slower.

That will make your line look like:

```
$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 0, ';');
```

Even though you may not need the whole line from the file, you are still going to get it, because that is the way fgetcsv works.

This array is zero indexed, so your column1 will be in position 0.

Once you have the line you can use the fields you need such as:

```
if ($line_of_text[11] == 'word')
    // do something

if (($line_of_text[7] - $line_of_text[9]) / $line_of_text[9] >= 0.05)
    // do something
```